# Possible meaning of "running past" on this phrase

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm an English student and I have a question about this sentence. It comes from a song, here's an excerpt:

> If you feel like giving up now
>
> Turn it into a smile
>
> You'll see new days are running past
>
> Just keep looking ahead

My question is what "running past" would mean here. I would say two things: days passing quickly or days falling behind, but I'm not sure if even one of those possibilities is correct.

Comment: I think the context suggests that you will see time passing quickly, and that this is to be hoped-for because you are now experiencing hard times and feel like giving up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And if that question has an answer, perhaps the answerer can also tell us what "it" refers to.

Answer (score 2):

As George Lakoff reports in *[Metaphors We Live By](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/L&J-Lg-Review.pdf)*,

> “Charles Fillmore has observed (in conversation) that English appears to have two contradictory organizations of time. In the first, the future is in front and the past is behind:
>
> - *In the weeks **ahead of us***  (future)
> - *That’s all **behind us** now.* (past)
>
> "In the second, the future is behind and the past is in front:
>
> - *In the **following** weeks* (future)
> - *In the **preceding** weeks* (past)
>
> "Moreover, the apparently contradictory metaphors can mix with no ill effect, as in
>
> - *We’re looking **ahead** to the **following** weeks.* "

In both of these scenarios the speaker (*Ego*, experiencing time, and life, and like that) is placed on a Path (Life is a Path is a common theme in metaphors) and, depending on individual details, either moves toward the future or experiences the future turning into the present around them without having to move -- the Path comes to you.

In the poem, the two lines

> *You'll see new days are **running past***
> *Just keep looking **ahead***

the boldfaced parts refer to the last part above -- the Path is moving rapidly around you as time passes, but you're sposta keep looking toward the future, even if you can't see it.

Metaphors of one sort or another are the only way we can talk about Time, so when it's referred to, watch out for the metaphors. They can get mixed easily.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a famous Chinese poem: “山穷水尽疑无路，柳暗花明又一村。” “The mountains exhausted, rivers ended and you’re sceptical that there’s no way forward. The willows dark, the flowers bright, there emerges another village.”  It conveys a similar idea. It doesn’t mean the days passing quickly or slowly as this is not the point here. Nor the days falling behind a concern here. What’s important is to watch the news days coming one by one, with a smile.

Answer (score 0):

It means that days are passing.